# Does forwarding a DNS to another server takes any resources?

Tags: domain-name-system, linode

I have a server hosted by linode. I just finished a job for a customer and want to move his site to *his* server.

The current DNS records are pointing to my Linode server, but his site is now hosted elsewhere.

If instead of him changing his DNS entries and setting up his own domain, if I forward the site from my Linode server to his IP, will this be using my bandwidth (or other) resources?

Is this recommendable or is it better that he actually changes the DNS records to his new server?

Comment: Why do you not want to forward the DNS entries?

Comment: The customer thinks is too complicated to be done by them and they don't want to give me access to the domain at godaddy ... plus they know this can be done but I don't want to say yes if it is going to use any of my resources or if it's something stupid to do :P

Comment: Well, if they're happy to pay for your bandwidth and have a slower, more unreliable site - then keep at it.

Comment: so it does take some of my bandwidth? (sorry I have really no idea how this works)

Comment: This is not DNS forwarding, but something else; what it is exactly depends on how you do it.  DNS forwarding is when one resolver forwards a DNS query to another resolver instead of recursively finding the answer itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will require network bandwidth and CPU time on your server for it to receive and forward the DNS queries.  Very likely it will be a modest amount, but it will require some.

I would be more concerned that you will also become an additional point of failure in the design -- if your forwarders stop working, the client's DNS stops working.  Why would you want that additional responsibility? (And why would they want that, too?)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a good reason for needlessly forwarding traffic - you'll just be adding a bottleneck.

Point the DNS to where the site is supposed to be.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick answer ... yes I also didn't think it was the best of the ideas but I want to have a good reason to tell them to just change their domain servers